I have used Fluent Wait and ignored noSuchElementException also I have used customized function. But the progrm still throws noSuchElementException
//Code
    driver.get("https://demoqa.com/elements");
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
    wait.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);  //exception ignored
    Function<WebDriver, WebElement> fun = new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver t) {
    WebElement element = t.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'text-danger')]"));
       if (element!=null) {
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("class"));
        return element;
       }
       long d = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println(d);
       return element;
    } 
    };
    WebElement element = wait.until(fun);
    //rest of code

**Basically, the program should wait for dynamic element to change it's class name after some point and print the new class name.**


The element that I written at first won't have the expected "text-danger" in it. But after 5 sec it's        class changes and will eventually have that string at that point my code should get into the if and should print the class attribute. But instead it throws no such exception at the first attempt of finding the element.
Which must not happen as I ignored it in first place.
I have tried changing the timeout and Pooling time no improvement. Where I'm going Wrong.*


There is no such element //button[contains(@class,'text-danger')] in the HTML document on https://demoqa.com/elements. I checked manually.
